# Get method not able to be detected by the Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am new to node and express js.Today I am learning and I have initialized node server as:

```
  const express = require('express')
    const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
    const cors = require('cors')

    const PORT = 3000
    const api=require('./routes/api')
    const app = express()
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    app.use(cors())

    api.use('/api',api)

    app.get('/', function(req, res) {
        res.send('Hello from server')
    })

   app.listen(PORT, function(){
  console.log("Server running on localhost:" + PORT)
});
```

I have created a folder **routes** inside **server** folder and there is **api.js** file which has **GET** method to test, whether the api is working or not.Inside **api.js** I have,

```
const express = require('express')
const router=express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('from Api Route');
})

module.exports=router
```

I type `node server` and it is displaying me :

```
Server running on localhost:3000
```

But,when I try to get the url:  **http://localhost:3000/api**,it is displaying me:

[image]

And,in api.js file in the arrow function sublime is showing me error in red marker as:

[image]

Comment: can u show me the proper syntax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `api.use('/api',api)` with `app.use('/api',api)`